# What can I blow up?

Tags: futuridium-ep

I noticed that there's a particular element in Futuridium that you can break through easily by shooting.  It looks like a stack of boxes.  It seems you have to break through it in some stages in order to get a good line on power cubes.

[image: Destucible boxes]

However, I also noticed just now that you can destroy the automated laser turrets and missile launchers.

[image: Laser Turret]

[image: Missile Launcher]

What elements can I destroy? Is there anything else?  Is it safe to assume you can blow up any hostile elements that might appear in later levels?